# How to integrate using differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

$$\int _0^{\infty }x^2e^{-ax^2}dx$$

where $a > 0,$ given that
$\displaystyle\int _0^{\infty }e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}}
$.
Not sure where to begin with this

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Answer (score 2):

For fixed $x$, let $f_x(a)=e^{-ax^2}$. Then $\frac d {da}f_x(a)=-x^2e^{-ax^2}$. So, given
$$\int_0^{\infty}f_x(a)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}}$$
we see that
$$\int_0^{\infty}x^2f_x(a)dx=\int_0^\infty -\frac d {da}f_x(a)dx=-\frac d {da}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{a}}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4\sqrt{a^3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
For $a \ne 0$:
$$I=\int _0^{\infty }x^2e^{-ax^2}dx=-\dfrac 1 {2a}\int _0^{\infty }x(-2axe^{-ax^2})dx$$
Integrate by parts.